# ServiceStack assembly issue - ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

After installing ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer NuGet Packages, I started getting below error out of no clue.

```
Method 'RemoveExpiredEntries' in type 'ServiceStack.Caching.MemoryCacheClient' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=02c12cbda47e6587' does not have an implementation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates you have different version of ServiceStack packages. You need to make sure that **all packages have the same version**, e.g. **5.9.0**.

Or if you're using the [pre-release MyGet packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget) (e.g ending 5.*.1) then you'll need to [clear out your NuGet packages cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages) so you can download the latest version, e.g:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

Comment: Updating ServiceStack packages to latest solved issue, thanks.